# jQuery Validator Minimum Required Words

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm looking for a way to validate some input textareas using jQuery -- unfortunately as awesome as the jQuery validator plugin is, it lacks the validation (to my knowledge) "minimum required words". I don't have the code with me (I'll edit in the morning), but I wrote a function that counts the words in your input, but that wasn't clean validation like the plugin  provides.

I also looked into word-and-character-count.js, but that also does not provide a minimum word count in order to submit the form.

Edit: the answer I provided is a custom validator method -- if anybody knows any cleaner methods or even an easy to use plugin, please let me know.

Comment: Whoever voted to close for the reason of minimal understanding needed: if I answered my own question for the benefit of others, does that not demonstrate beyond minimal understanding..?

Comment: There's a bit more to that off-topic reason:  _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"_

Comment: I don't understand, I had no previous code for validation. When I found no solutions on google, I wrote a custom method, and it worked with my expected results.

Comment: IMO, both the question and the answer should be self-contained.  In other words, the quality of the question should not depend on the answer.  Anyway, just my opinion and it won't get closed unless four others agree.

Comment: The problem is not that you answered your own question, it's that the question is more like a comment/preface to the answer. You should edit it into a question that conforms to the site guidelines.

Comment: Oh!! My mistake, I'll edit that now. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Function to get the live word count, excluding the spaces at the end (simply splitting will count say `word` (note the space at the end) as 2 words.

```
function getWordCount(wordString) {
  var words = wordString.split(" ");
  words = words.filter(function(words) { 
    return words.length > 0
  }).length;
  return words;
}

//add the custom validation method
jQuery.validator.addMethod("wordCount",
   function(value, element, params) {
      var count = getWordCount(value);
      if(count >= params[0]) {
         return true;
      }
   },
   jQuery.validator.format("A minimum of {0} words is required here.")
);

//call the validator
selector:
{
    required: true,
    wordCount: ['30']
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but why an array argument?

Comment: I was thinking expandability, if somebody wanted to add on to this for say.. maybe a min/max method, they could use it array style for simplicity. Redundant here, but not so much overhead that I kept it simple I guess.

Comment: The answer only worked for me when I replaced ```jQuery.format``` with ```jQuery.validator.format```. This is an old answer though, so it's possible that the jQuery Validation plugin had changed its API after this answer had been posted.

Comment: Oh definitely, this answer was created when I believe jQuery 1.x was still a thing. I have no idea if it's still relevant to modern versions (I do not use jQuery anymore)